# Querying MongoDB with keyword

Tags: search, mongodb

I have big collection of tweets stored in MongoDB. Tweets look like this one:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("4c02c58de500fe1be1000005"),
"contributors" : null,
"text" : "Hello world",
"user" : {
    "following" : null,
    "followers_count" : 5,
    "utc_offset" : null,
    "location" : "",
    "profile_text_color" : "000000",
    "friends_count" : 11,
    "profile_link_color" : "0000ff",
    "verified" : false,
    "protected" : false,
    "url" : null,
    "contributors_enabled" : false,
    "created_at" : "Sun May 30 18:47:06 +0000 2010",
    "geo_enabled" : false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "87bc44",
    "statuses_count" : 13,
    "favourites_count" : 0,
    "description" : "",
    "notifications" : null,
    "profile_background_tile" : false,
    "lang" : "en",
    "id" : 149978111,
    "time_zone" : null,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "e0ff92"
},
"geo" : null,
"coordinates" : null,
"in_reply_to_user_id" : 149183152,
"place" : null,
"created_at" : "Sun May 30 20:07:35 +0000 2010",
"source" : "web",
"in_reply_to_status_id" : {
    "floatApprox" : 15061797850
},
"truncated" : false,
"favorited" : false,
"id" : {
    "floatApprox" : 15061838001
```

For example, If I want to find tweets about some topic for example, canon, then How should I write a query which checks the "text" and finds all tweets about "canon"?

Comment: Thanks I didn't know how to make it look like that)

Comment: You just highlight it and hit the Code Sample button in the top toolbar. It needs 4 space indents to be "code"

Comment: -1 for asking the a question without having done zero research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB does not have directly native query support to search within text. There is official documentation showing you how you can achieve a simple approach to full text search:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Full+Text+Search+in+Mongo

It involves splitting the text into words, and storing them in an array, which you index. This lets you match against the contents of an array. How you split them up is your choice. Maybe you just do words, lowercase, and match against a lower case keyword. Or maybe you need autocompletion so you do variations of each word, or phonetics, etc. Thats all stemming.

Its not as robust as a full text search engine, designed to do this, but it works. Depending on the language you are using, some frameworks have search packages. For instance, I use mongodb with [django's nonrel project](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/django-nonrel), and there is a [search app](http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/nonrel-search) for that which provides stemming and different tool for searching.

Comment: I'm using Ruby so can I do search with Ruby?  It's just in MogoDB I have to split all text to the keywords, but I have a big collection of tweets so it seems unreal to split them all(((

Comment: @DulosAdam: You would have to search for a Ruby package that provides this. Otherwise, you have to do it manually. Every time a change is made to the document/field you have to reindex using whatever stemming method you decide on. Read that link I posted to see how you go about it.

Comment: @DulosAdam: It may seem unreal, but thats what you would have to do. You decide what fields you want to index. Then you split them how you want into maybe a private field. And you ensureIndex on that field. Thats just how you have to do it. In the django search package, they actually create a relation collection to store the indexed words separate from the original document.

Comment: @Dulos Adam:  exactly. Thats a full text search engine. So you would have to coordinate storing the data in there and link back to your mongo database for the documents. But Im doing it now with mongo and its pretty fast.

Comment: @Dulos Adam: glad to help. Dont forget to hit the green checkmark for the answer if it solved your question.